# how to calculate ppi of this camera?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

My camera is **HIKIROBOT MV-CE060-10UC 6MP USB Camera** and its lens is  **HIKIROBOT MVL-HF2528M-6MPE 25MM lens**

Camera Resolution : 3072 x 2048 == 6 MP

[more details about camera](https://www.rmaelectronics.com/hikrobot-mv-ce060-10uc/)

[more details about lens](https://www.rmaelectronics.com/hikrobot-mvl-hf2528m-6mpe/)

and the operating distance 370 mm.

My need is find the Dimensions of object using python. I try some method its not give accurate value.

I search in online to calculate the ppi [link of website](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/technology/ppi-calculator.php).I follow the steps to calculate ppi but i don't know the **diagonal in inches**
[diagonal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RypTc.png)

That website give some examples to calculate the ppi like

They calculate the ppi of computer screen here thay give diagonal inches of screen, but in my case don't know the daigonal inches. What to do ?

Comment: cameras don't have "ppi". did you calibrate the camera to estimate its intrinsics?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes I already done the calibrate the camera to estimate its intrinsics. but whats the relationship between intrinsics and ppi.

Comment: *did you take the [tour] yet?* -- assuming you have the focal length (in px), and a "working distance" (parallel plane) at 370 mm away, and you want to calculate the "ppi" **on that plane only**...  the projection equation yields `f * (1 inch / ppi) / (370 mm) = 1` so you can rearrange to get `ppi`. hint: with `f=1400`, you get ~96.1 ppi.

Comment: or just put a ruler on your surface, figure out how many pixels are what distance on the ruler, and done... it's simple.

Comment: yeah, its true. I already tried that ruler method. In that method we facing some issues, we are taken 1 cm in the middle of the surface, its have 255 pixels. At the same 1 cm we are taken in the corner its shows 257 pixels. we don't know how to solve that.

Comment: you don't know how to "solve" a measuring inaccuracy of 0.4%, which is _one pixel_ more or less than the average? either accept it or see that you undistort the image using the distortion coefficients.